# How to Sort objects by 2 fields Java

Tags: java, multithreading, data-structures, filereader, mergesort

The file I am trying to read looks like this:

```
1995     Pokemon    Ikue Ôtani  
1940     Tom and Jerry    William Hanna 
1995     Pokemon    voice actor2
1940     Tom and Jerry    voice actor3
2000     Cartoon      voice actor
```

It has around 20k rows. I already got the reading the file and storing the data in an object.

```
        in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(cartoonsFile));
            
        ArrayList<String> voiceActors = new ArrayList<>();  
        ArrayList<Cartoon> cartoons = new ArrayList<>();    
        
        //read each line
        String line = in.readLine();
        while (line != null) {
            String[] columns = line.split("\\t");
            String year = columns[0];
            String cartoon = columns[1];
            String voiceActor = columns[2];

            //make new object and store data

            Cartoon c = new Cartoon(Integer.parseInt(columns[0]),
                                    columns[1], columns[2]));
            cartoons.add(c); //add to the array list
```

Object

```
public class Cartoon {
  private int year;
  private String title;
  private String voiceActor;

  public Cartoon(int year, String title, String voiceActor) {
    this.year = year;
    this.title = title;
    this.voiceActor = voiceActor;
  }
};
```

I would like to read the file in threads and sort by year. Can anyone provide sample code on how can multithread and merge sort be implemented together?

The output that I'd like to get

```
1940     Tom and Jerry         William Hanna 
                               voice actor2
                               voice actor3
                               voice actor4
                               voice actor5

1995     Pokemon               Ikue Ôtani  
                               voice actor2

         A Cartoon             voice actor1
                               voice actor2
                               voice actor3

2000     Cartoon               voice actor
```

Comment: Your question is lacking information: Your code looks like there is only one voice actor per film, but your desired output looks as if there might be multiple ones. I cannot see where/how you parse that. There is no full description of the input format, I cannot see the crucial class `CartoonYear` either (bad class name, BTW).

Comment: Ah okay, after you last edit I can see how the input file is organised in case of multiple voice actors per film. I think it would be better to create a `Cartoon` class which can have multiple voice actors instead of many redundant ones.

Comment: Then I'll change the CartoonYear to 'Year' class which will hold multiple Cartoon classes right?

Comment: That's not what I meant. I was rather thinking about a `Cartoon` class with year, title and a list or set of speakers. But based on your own approach and @saka1029's answer you could also use Java streams and `Collectors.groupingBy`. But then you would need some kind of helper class grouping by year + title (only year is not unique). I can post a quick example.

Comment: Why? 20,000 entries isn't a large file, and will be sorted in a few nanoseconds however you do it. There's no need for multi-threading this.

Comment: it's just a sample number. I wanted to see a sample of how multithreading and mergesort work in reading a file because I'm new to the topics...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sticking with your data structure (just renaming it from the rather peculiar `CartoonYear` to `Cartoon`), and also sticking with the good approach of using Java streams by @saka1029 (instead of manually implementing a merge sort algorithm), you could do something like this:

```java
package org.acme;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Cartoon {
  private int year;
  private String title;
  private String voiceActor;

  public Cartoon(int year, String title, String voiceActor) {
    this.year = year;
    this.title = title;
    this.voiceActor = voiceActor;
  }

  public static Map<String, List<Cartoon>> readAndGroupByYearAndTitle(String inFile) throws IOException {
    return Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(inFile))
      .parallelStream()
      .map(line -> line.split("\\t"))
      .map(columns -> new Cartoon(Integer.parseInt(columns[0]), columns[1], columns[2]))
      .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(cartoon -> String.format("%4d %s", cartoon.year, cartoon.title)));
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Map<String, List<Cartoon>> cartoonsGrouped = readAndGroupByYearAndTitle(args[0]);
    cartoonsGrouped.keySet()
      .parallelStream()
      .sorted()
      .forEachOrdered(group -> {
        boolean firstElement = true;
        for (Cartoon cartoonYear : cartoonsGrouped.get(group)) {
          if (firstElement) {
            System.out.printf("%4d  %-25s  %s%n", cartoonYear.year, cartoonYear.title, cartoonYear.voiceActor);
            firstElement = false;
          }
          else
            System.out.printf("%4s  %-25s  %s%n", "", "", cartoonYear.voiceActor);
        }
      });
  }
}
```

This was just quick & dirty, not code I am proud of. Your requirement to only print year and title once per group does not make the code nicer with the `if-else` either. But assuming you have an input file like this:

```
1995    Pokemon Ikue Ôtani
1940    Tom and Jerry   William Hanna
11  Sample  foo
1995    Pokemon voice actor2
1940    Tom and Jerry   voice actor3
2000    Cartoon voice actor
11  Sample  bar
```

you will get output like this:

```
  11  Sample                     foo
                                 bar
1940  Tom and Jerry              William Hanna
                                 voice actor3
1995  Pokemon                    Ikue Ôtani
                                 voice actor2
2000  Cartoon                    voice actor
```

Comment: This is nice! Would it be too much to ask if you could provide a sample too on of how multithreading and mergesort work in reading a file? Hypothetically if the file is large enough to need them.

Comment: Yes, this is definitely asking too much because it is not how SO works. You show your own implementation, explaining and reproducing your problem(s) with it, others look into it and help you fix it. It is not like "hey, I got a problem, solve it for me completely and for free".

Comment: As for Merge Sort, it was introduced as a sequential sort algorithm. Which part do you want to parallelise? The recursive "divide" phase would be trivial, but does not make it so much faster. More complex is parallel merge, especially k-way merge (not just 2-way). Please also note that merge sort was invented for multiple data sources (dating back to when data to be merged were read from multiple tapes). You said you only have a single list file. You would have to split it first before reading it, otherwise reading would be sequential (just like in my example above) and only sorting parallel.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
List<CartoonYear> readAndSortByYear(String inFile) throws IOException {
    return Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(inFile))
        .parallelStream()
        .map(line -> line.split("\\t"))
        .map(columns -> new CartoonYear(Integer.parseInt(columns[0]), columns[1], columns[2]))
        .sorted(Comparator.comparing(CartoonYear::getYear))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: There is no grouping in your solution.